# 70-576 Study Material

Tags: exams, recommendations

I'm having trouble finding background material for Microsoft's exam [70-576](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-576&locale=en-us#tab2): "Designing and Developing Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Applications".

Most of the syllabus consists of what a developer like myself would (politely) call "woolly" requirements. As a result, any research turns up an enormous list of articles that are mostly irrelevant.

Are they any particularly good study guides for this exam (online or tree-based)?

Comment: Check out the official exam page with in detail information on what will be asked for - https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-576#tab2

Comment: @moontear: Or alternatively click the link in my question? Apparently most of that syllabus consists of "woolly" requirements. ;)

Comment: If you were able to pass the MCTS exam then this one is a walk in the park. Not a single line of code appears in the exam.

Comment: @James: I'm studying for both at the same time... Presumably this means it'll either be a double triumph or a cluster-fail.

Comment: Missed your link. Thought the requirements are pretty "standard" like they are for all MS exams - test exam questions really help the preparation - you can always find some using your favorite search engine ;-)

Comment: @moontear: I managed to find the below using the aforementioned engine fortunately, but the vast majority of results are the same template "Buy Exam [number] questions here for your [number] exam needs for [system] expertise!"

Comment: @moontear: Additionally, with regards to searching advice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: @Stuart In general this holds true for searching, but many people are unaware that especially for exam material there are lots of good hits on search engines **plus** illegal downloads to complete questionnaires (or so called braindumps) - this should not be advertised on SO, but is a fact and hence the searching advise holds true for exam related questions.

Comment: @moontear: With this clarification I'd agree that nodding meaningfully towards a search engine is warranted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a little digging this afternoon, and [found the following from Pedro Pinto](http://sharepointstream.com/2011/01/21/study-guide-to-the-exam-70-576-microsoft-sharepoint-2010-designing-and-developing/).

It seems quite comprehensive so far, if understandably vague (given the depth of the subject). It needs an editor's eye to be honest, but the content is there.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer for now since it's free and pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a Dev by any means and I took this exam. It really is more about design and logic than about actual developer code. So those articles that you are reading are probably more relevant than you think. Since there are no preparation materials or books to prepare you for this exam, I would review the list of skills measured (moontear links to them in the comments) and see what areas you might feel less confident about and research those. In my case, I read articles and blog posts, mostly to prepare.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I feared, unfortunately; that it's an exam for general background knowledge and experience rather than easily definable areas (like 70-573 is, mostly).

Answer (score 3):

This was mentioned over on the 70-573 question by @Tim Gabrhell, but it covers material for both exams:

[Cram Session: SharePoint Certification Exam Prep](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEtOf7Hq4yw&feature=BFa&list=PLB567137EA30A37BE&index=1)

Answer (score 3):

There is also [this blog post](http://tchmiel.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/70-576-study-materials/) that contains some more links to study materials for the 70-576 exam.

I can also add that the [Inside SharePoint 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627460) book was very helpful for me when taking the 70-573 exam, and according to one of it's authors (Ted Pattison), the book also covers a lot of what you'll find on the 70-576 exam.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a course for this exam: [10232A Designing and Developing SharePoint Server 2010 Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/course.aspx?ID=10232a#tab1).

Comment: Go to course. Microsoft still has the course and you can apply and be part of the students. A saw that the course is for 5 days. So I think it worth.